# How do I query for the sum of averages?

Tags: mysql

I have data that resemble stock data that is being updated every hour. So there are 24 entries every day for each stock. (just using stock as an example). But sometimes, the data may not be updated.

For example, let's assume we have 3 stocks, A, B, C. And assume that we gather data at various intervals during the day for each stock. The data would look something like this...

```
row   A    B    C
 1    3    4    5
 2    3.5  4.1  5
 3    2.9  3.8  4.3
```

What I want is to sum up the average value of each stock for this time period or
    Avg(A) + Avg(B) + Avg(C)

In reality I have hundreds of stocks and hundreds of thousands of rows. I need this to calculate for a single day.

I tried this (stock names are in an array - stocks = array('A','B','C'))

```
SELECT SUM(AVG(stock_price)) FROM table WHERE date = [mydate] AND stock_name IN () ('".implode("','", $stocks)."') GROUP BY stock_name
```

but that didn't work. Can someone provide some insight?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I'm sure there is a better way, but you could select the avg of each stock as a variable, then calculate the sum on it.

Comment: Is each stock really in a different column of the same row? Or is there actually a row for each stock?

Comment: Each stock is on a separate row. I just displayed the data in a table for clarity. Each row in my DB table contains id, stock_price, stock_name and date.

Comment: cwhelms - I was thinking of that but there are tens of thousands of stocks. That is a lot of SQL calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the per-stock averages in a sub-query, then sum them in the main query.

```
SELECT SUM(average_price) AS total_averages
FROM (SELECT AVG(price) AS average_price)
      FROM table
      WHERE <conditions>
      GROUP BY stock_name) AS averages
```

Comment: Seems like something is missing... Doesn't each select portion need a table specified? Shouldn't the SELECT be on a WHERE clause?  I am getting the error "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: The subquery is the specified table for the outer query. And the `x` at the end is the alias for that derived table.

Comment: I've given it a more descriptive alias now.

Comment: So I should make it x.average_price... :)

Comment: You could, but you don't need to. You only have to specify `table.col` when the column names are ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks that was it! I went full syntax like the example below, which is essentially the same response.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, use an inline view as a rowsource:

```
SELECT SUM(a.avg_stock_price) AS sum_avg_stock_price
  FROM ( SELECT AVG(t.stock_price) AS avg_stock_price
           FROM table t
          WHERE t.date = [mydate]
            AND t.stock_name IN ('a','b','c')
          GROUP BY t.stock_name
       ) a
```

You can run just the query from the inline view (aliased as a) to get verify the results it returns. The outer query runs against the set of rows returned by the inline view query. (MySQL refers to the inline view (aliased as `a`) as a "derived table".

The outer query is effectively like this:

```
SELECT SUM(a.avg_stock_price) AS sum_avg_stock_price
  FROM a
```

The "trick" is that `"a"` isn't a regular table, it's a set of rows returned by a query; but in terms of relational algebra theory, it works the same... it's a set or rows.  If `a` were a regular table, we could write:

```
SELECT b.col
  FROM (
         SELECT col FROM a
       ) b
```

We don't want to do that in MySQL when we don't have to, because of the inefficient way that MySQL processes that. MySQL first runs the inner query (the query in the inline view). MySQL creates a  temporary MyISAM table, and inserts the rows returned by the query into the temporary MyISAM table. MySQL then runs the outer query, against that temporary table (which MySQL refers to as a "derived table") to return the result. Creating and populating a temporary table that's a copy of a regular table is a lot of overhead, especially with large sets.

What makes this powerful is that inline view query can include JOINs, WHERE clause, aggregates, GROUP BY, whatever. As long as it returns a set of rows (with appropriate column names), we can wrap the query in parens, and reference it in another query like it was a table.

Comment: Thanks Spencer. I accepted the previous answer since he was first and they were essentially the same.